# how to set value to specific object of array object in javasript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have to write inputbox inner a looping statement.
let say I have 3 times loop

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; i<3;i++){
?>
      <input type="number" id="numb" onkeyup="getvalue(this.value)"/>
      <span id="result"></result>
<?php
    }
?>

<script>
function getvalue(val){
        var res= parseInt(val)*10;
        if(isNaN(res) == true){
            res = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('result').value = res;

}
</script>
```

the question is, how to set every value I type in inputbox only settbthe result
inner span from its row index only

Comment: ID attributes MUST be unique. You are declaring the same ID multiple times and hoping that the function will know which element is referred to when using `document.getElementById` - it won't!

Comment: What object? What array of object?

Comment: In the `for` loop all the `i` variables must start with `$` : `for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more luck trying an approach like this. Remove the ID attributes from the elements - you can replace with class names if you like or remove entirely from the `span` element as it should not necessarily be required to allow you to target it programmatically. If you use `sibling` selectors you can use the `target` attribtute of the `event` ( in this case keyup within the number element ) and then traverse the DOM to find the span...

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
?>
      <input type="number" class="numb" onkeyup="getvalue(event)"/>
      <span class="result"></span>
<?php
    }
?>

<script>
    function getvalue(e){
        var node=e.target.nextElementSibling;
        var res=parseInt(e.target.value) * 10;
        if( isNaN(res) )res=0;
        node.textContent=res;
    }
</script>
```

```js
function getvalue(e){
  var node=e.target.nextElementSibling;
  var res=parseInt(e.target.value) * 10;
  if( isNaN(res) )res=0;
  node.textContent=res;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="getvalue(event)" />
<span></span>
<input type="number" onkeyup="getvalue(event)" />
<span></span>
<input type="number" onkeyup="getvalue(event)" />
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the input that the user is typing in it bye getting the event object and the target property of that. That event.target (input element) has a property called nextElementSibling.

Use the nextElementSibling to access the next element after the input which here it is the span.

No need to use id or other methods

Change the input element to:

```
<input type="number" class="numb" onkeyup="getvalue(event)"/>
```

Change the script tag content to:

```
function getvalue(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var val = input.value;
  var res = parseInt(val) * 10;
  if (isNaN(res) == true) {
    res = 0;
  }
  input.nextElementSibling.textContent = res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id for each input and it related result span. The id will just be the `$i` of the for loop. This will help to easily access the specified result span in the `getvalue` function:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
?>
    <div>
        <input type="number" data-input-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" onkeyup="getvalue(this)" >
        <span class="result-<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
function getvalue (element) {
    const inputId = element.dataset.inputId;
    const val = element.value;
    let res = parseInt(val) * 10;
    res = isNaN(res) ? 0 : res;

    
     document.querySelector(`.result-${inputId}`).innerText = res;
}
</script>
```